# Doc filter vs changed listener

Tags: java, swing, changelistener, documentfilter

I have set up a doc filter that only allows, only numbers to inserted into the `JTextField`, I want to run a method that does stuff when the content of on `JTextField` is changed.

Which is better run the method from my doc filter or setup event handler (ok they are called listener in Java) Which is better for performance, if does not make much difference, is one considered better practice when it comes to Java dev?

Comment: Personally 'field + only numbers' says `JSpinner` with `SpinnerNumberModel` (with a `ChangeListener` attached) to me.

Comment: Spinner looks good, did not know the exist, but not really useful in content of my app

Answer (score 2):

A `DocumentFilter` can be used for editing the text as it is entered. Or you could use a `JFormattedTextField` (which uses a DocumentFilter).

A `DocumentListener` should be used for being notified when the text is changed.

Comment: So you are saying i should use a 'DocumentListener' do stuff when text is change over, add the method the the 'DocumentFilter'

Comment: @user2842801, Correct. If you type "a" then the DocumentFilter will reject the character so the DocumentListener is never invoked. The DocumentListener will only be invoked if you insert a valid number (or remove a number).